# Why does instantiating Google Maps PlacesSearch add an ugly white div to the map?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Why does creating an instance of `google.maps.places.PlacesService` add a translucent white div to the right side of the map?

See the image below, where I've highlighted the `<div>` that gets added by `PlacesSearch` using Chrome's DevTools (the div appears in all of the browsers I tested, including Chrome, Firefox, and Edge). This div gets added at the exact moment that this line is called in JavaScript:

```
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
```

The screenshot below is taken from Google's own documentation page:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search

At the time of this writing, that page is using Google Maps JavaScript API version `3.31.2`, but it also occurs on my own site using version `3.29.14b`, so it seems like this problem has been around for at least a few versions now.

You can also see it in action here: https://jsfiddle.net/q7788qvp/ If you click the "Instantiate" button multiple times, you can see multiple white translucent divs get stacked up on the right side of the map.

Is there any way to prevent this div from being added to the map?

---

[image: Google Maps white translucent div]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [open issue (#35828183) in the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35828183)

One workaround to prevent the `<div>` from being added to the `map`, would be to pass the `PlacesService` constructor an `HTMLElement` rather than the `map` object.

```
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.getElementById('placediv'));
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/q7788qvp/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map($("#map")[0], {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    zoom: 17,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4219006, -122.0847023)
  });

  $("button").on("click", function() {
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.getElementById('placediv'));
  });
});
```

```css
#map {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 40px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=places"></script>
<div id="placediv"></div>
<button>Instantiate PlacesSearch</button>
<div id="map"></div>
```